# Grub loads after rEFInd

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, refit

I have a dual-boot UEFI laptop, with Ubuntu and Windows. I installed rEFInd to boot to these systems, and it worked fine, but my linux system was triplicated. I supposed it was because of rEFInd searching for any `vmlinuz` and all these, so I added the line `scan_all_linux_kernels 0` into `refind.conf`.

After this, the extra booting options disappeared, but when I select Ubuntu, I get the GRUB menu to select it again.

I want to disable GRUB, so that the system boots from rEFInd. I have tried to `apt-get remove` all grub and grub2 packages, but GRUB still appears.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have solved it, although I don't understand why.

I have reinstalled grub, but telling it NOT to generate `menu.lst`

I have renamed `/boot/grub/`to `/boot/grub_back/`, which has broken the boot. From a live USB boot, I have renamed it back to original and, after this, GRUB doesn't start any more after rEFInd.

Problem solved, but in a strange way.

Answer (score 1):

Your GRUB is still starting; it's just that it's not presenting a menu any more. A cleaner solution is to change `scan_all_linux_kernels 0` back to `scan_all_linux_kernels` in `refind.conf`, uninstall GRUB via `dpkg` or `apt-get`, and then trim any duplicate entries in the rEFInd menu in a more targeted way. I can't be more precise about this last point without knowing precisely what the existing options are, though. Also, be aware that in some configurations, you *should* have multiple Linux options in rEFInd, since each one boots a different kernel. This is equivalent to having multiple Linux entries in GRUB, each of which boots a different kernel.